# Cannot scan (documents) to Samba share when using SMBv2

Tags: samba, cifs, smb, scanner

On my Debian Buster I have a Samba share that works fine from both Windows and Linux clients.
I've configured the Samba with `min protocol = SMB2` in smb.conf and with local user/password authentication (no AD).

But I'm not able to connect to the share from neither my Brother network document-scanner nor my HP MFP (using CIFS).
These devices connect fine to shares on Windows computers where SMBv1 is disabled (I assume SMBv2 must be used then).

If I remark `min protocol = SMB2` on my Samba server they connect fine! Can it be anything else than a bad `SMBv2` implementation on the devices? A firmware update to the HP printer didn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions are welcome :-)

UPDATE:

I started to read the smbd manual now :-/

I increased the log-level using `log level = 5` in smb.conf, remarked `n protocol = SMB2` and then did a scan-session. I can see in the log for the session (/var/log/samba/log.10.0.1.20) that it is actually using smb2_02. So I just need to dig a little more so see why it goes wrong when setting the mininum protocal level.

Answer (score 1):

The manual says

> By default SMB2 selects the SMB2_10 variant.

And I can see my HP MFP sent the request `Requested protocol [SMB 2.002]`

So I just had to use this option instead: `server min protocol = SMB2_02`

*(FYI `min protocol` is a synonym of `server min protocol`)*

And my Brother 2600W documents scanner is also using SMB 2.02 so it's also working now :-)